# DOMXpath returns nothing

Tags: php, html, xpath, domxpath

my head is hurting.
I recently made a website and used DOMXpath. It worked perfectly with URL.
Now i want to get stuff from a html file in the same folder.
Suddenly the simpliest thing becomes the most asked.
I don't even know why it's not working with a file and not with URL.
Here are the files:

```
error_reporting(0);
include_once "db_config.php";
$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. "today.html";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]");
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $name = $node->nodeValue;
      echo $name;
  }
}
```

And here is today.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>aaaaa</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="col2 centertd">ΑΥΣΛ</td>
    <td class="col3 centertd">10:50</td>
    <td class="col4 centertd">1985</td>
    <td class="col5 centertd">3,30</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please anything could help.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Remove tbody from your XPath.

Comment: Wow! my head was hurting and it was all about that tbody...
I can't describe how thankfull i am...

Answer (score 1):

Answered by: [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790838/markus)

I had to remove tbody from the XPath.